# Why is HttpURLConnection ignoring the header I want to send?

Tags: java, rest

I want to consume my own API from my backend, the issue is that when I do the request in backend
the header Sec-Fetch-Site is not sent.

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/prueba")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response prueba(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
        String message = "OK";
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> rh = headers.getRequestHeaders();
        if (rh == null || rh.get("Sec-Fetch-Site") == null || !rh.get("Sec-Fetch-Site").get(0).equals("same-origin"))
            message = "Error";  
        
        return Response.ok(message).build();
    }
    
    @POST
    @Path("/prueba2")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response prueba2() {
          URL url;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/login/rest/auth/prueba");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                 throw new IOException("Error: " + responseCode);
                
                try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                         ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                       
                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I can consume /prueba2 without problem; however it fails if I try to consume /prueba from /prueba2. What am I doing wrong? Regards.

Comment: You have an API endpoint that does literally nothing but check if a request header is present, and throws an error if it isn't. You are then creating a new HTTP connection to that API endpoint without adding that header to the request. What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: This was an example, no a real scenario, I would like to know, how do i validate that my API is not consume for external app, but it can be consumed from my backend.

Comment: Add the request header to the request?

Comment: I did and i got the same result:

Comment: connection.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin"

Comment: Read your code again -- you are not adding the header (not in the version in your question, anyway, which is the only version we can help you with). And what exactly does "it fails" mean?

Comment: You should reconsider your architecture. You should move the business logic out of the endpoints. The endpoints should only be used from outside. Then you can call the other business logic function directly.

Comment: The problem is this is for my work, not my personal projects, so I can't do any change.

Comment: On the other hand, no matter if I send or not the header Sec-Fectch-Site, connection.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin"), when I consume prueba from prueba2 that header is not sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers starting with "sec-" are restricted by `HttpUrlConnection`, and won't be set on the request unless the system property `sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders` is set to `true`.

The Javadoc says:

```
/*
     * Restrict setting of request headers through the public api
     * consistent with JavaScript XMLHttpRequest2 with a few
     * exceptions. Disallowed headers are silently ignored for
     * backwards compatibility reasons rather than throwing a
     * SecurityException. For example, some applets set the
     * Host header since old JREs did not implement HTTP 1.1.
     * Additionally, any header starting with Sec- is
     * disallowed.
     *
     * The following headers are allowed for historical reasons:
     *
     * Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Cookie, Cookie2, Date,
     * Referer, TE, User-Agent, headers beginning with Proxy-.
     *
     * The following headers are allowed in a limited form:
     *
     * Connection: close
     *
     * See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2.
     */
```